# The meaning of 'fine-grained', 'fine-tuned' , 'fine-grining'

Tags: meaning

"The Portal provides fine-grained control over the window rendering"

what's the meaning of 'fine-grained' here?

Comment: I have ever heard of *grining*, though.  Perhaps *grinding*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means very precise control. For example, a volume control on a hifi with 3 volume settings could be described as 'coarse', whereas one with 20 settings would be 'fine'.

Comment: ![For really fine grained volume control, you'd want a 15 turn vernier potentiometer][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GgOKC.jpg